# Mongoose Query on Index Slow

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've got a query that gets quite often that I've identified as slow. It has index on every data point I query, though no compound indexes.

The query looks something like:

```
ExternalLead.find({
    'price': {$gte:3, $lt:6}, 
    "campaign.id":"an id", 
    createdOn: {$gte: new Date(moment().subtract(10, 'days')), 
                $lte: new Date(moment().subtract(5, 'min'))
    }}).limit(10).sort({_id:-1}).select('_id').exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var st = new Date();
    console.log(st - s);
});
```

Simple query, there are about 50k records for that query removing the price. Price is indexed, I'm 100% sure. I've verified it multiple ways. If I remove price this query finishes in about 200ms, with price it takes about 20 seconds. I've tested multiple price ranges, the first 10 it scanned should be a match. Is there something about this query that it's not using the indexes?

Also, the server is about 3x what this database needs right now, it's not a server issue. The entire database is loaded into ram.

Node 6.11.2,
Mongoose: 4.10.8,
mongodb-core: 2.1.1
MongoDb: 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we needed a compound index for price and createdOn.